# Why am I getting [object Object] on my axios GET request?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm making a react-express app, and am pulling the following data from a SQLite3 database:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'henry',
        photo: '/Photos/dog1.jpg'
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'boris',
        photo: '/Photos/dog2.jpg'
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name: 'Borker',
        photo: '/Photos/dog3.jpg'
    }
]
```

The back end is working fine, and returns the above object upon making GET requests in postman. I'm using the following set up:

```
//Route

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    db.getDogs()
    .then(dogs => {
        res.json(dogs)
    })
})

//API

export const getDogs =  () => {
 axios.get('/v1/dogs')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data) // **returns [object Object]**
        return res.data
    })
}

//API call in react component

import React from 'react'
import {getDogs} from '../api/indexApi'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      dogs:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getDogs()
    .then(dogs => {
      this.setState({
        dogs:dogs
      })
    })
  }
```

The problem is that the data I'm pulling is not rendering in the browser, and I think it has something to do with my axios get request - consoling logging the reponse from that request gave [object Object]. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: try `console.log(res)`, what you get?

Comment: and also separate the back-end code and front-end cow, so we can grasp it easily

Comment: your function `getDogs` does not return anything

Comment: @BloodyLogic for some wierd reason, I console logged res.data and it logged the array of objects I was looking for. Don't get why it suddenly started working. But it's still not rendering. I'll add more detailed code, by the way

Comment: have you created `baseURL` for `axios`? you need to provide full URL `axios.get('localhost:8000/api/dogs')`.

Comment: It doesn't render because the getDogs function doesn't return anything, like Ifaruki said. Change the first line to `return axios.get('/v1/dogs')`

Comment: Thanks guys - adding the proper URL fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you didn't provide the full API URL to `axios`, if you haven't created `baseURL` for `axios`, just provide the full URL `localhost:800/api/dogs`:

```
export const getDogs =  () => {
 return axios.get('localhost:8000/v1/dogs')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        return res.data
    })
}
```

You should be good to go!
[To create baseURL for axios, DRY](https://css-tricks.com/stay-dry-using-axios-for-api-requests/)

Comment: but what if I want to log full response that ```axios``` returns?
In this example, I want to get: ```console.log(res);```

Comment: @ConstantineCh just the return the `res` instead of `res.data`. happy coding!